# Are dictionaries off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

My question https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7035/903 has so far received 4 close votes. At the same time, the [dictionary](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) tag exists, and I see two others questions of IMHO the same kind without any close votes:

- [Maintained open source offline Japanese dictionary for Android?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/848/903) (5 upvotes, 0 close vote, 0 downvote)
- [Bilingual French-English dictionary for the Amazon Kindle](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7158/903)  (1 upvotes since migration , 0 close vote, 0 downvote)
- [Encyclopedia that works offline (alternative to Encarta)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7130/903)  (3 upvotes, 0 close vote, 0 downvote)
- [English to Greek Dictionary](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4501/903) (2 upvotes, 0 close vote, 0 downvote)

So, are dictionaries on- or off-topic?

Comment: I tend to answer this is "Software Recommendations" (not "Readers Digest"). If the question where e.g. for an Android App supporting offline dictionaries, that would be clearly on-topic (as the app is requested, not the content) – and here the mentioned tag would match. Hard to say. But besides, thanks for mentioning the others so we can VTC :) Honestly: those might have slipped through below the radar. Maybe edit your Q and add some functionality requirements (search etc), to make it clearly "software" and drop off the border-line?

Comment: (+1) Good to get this nice and clear.

Answer (score 4):

This is closely related to the distinction between software and data sources, which is [currently unresolved](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/data-sources-vs-applications-whats-the-limit).

All four dictionary questions listed in this meta question [1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/848/maintained-open-source-offline-japanese-dictionary-for-android) [2](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7158/bilingual-french-english-dictionary-for-the-amazon-kindle) [3](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4501/english-to-greek-dictionary) [4](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7130/windows-encarta-alternatives-that-work-offline) have a dual aspect: they cover both the software to access the dictionary and the dictionary content. Three of them have an offline requirement that make them heavy on the data source aspect; without an offline requirement, an answer could be “use this application which is able to query data sources using one or more standard or proprietary protocols”.

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/matlab-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-dictionary is different because it's purely about the data source. There's no non-trivial requirement that the data be queried with a particular workflow or within a particular environment. I think this makes it firmly off-topic, but we haven't settled this.

Comment: Thanks, so if I had asked to a Matlab <-> NumPy/SciPy/Matplotlib dictionary offline for Windows or Kindle then it would have been on-topic? I feel that adding this kind of software requirements could be a way to "circumvent" the data source issue. I do agree that drawing a clear line between software and data sources is tricky :/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt My personal feeling is that we're too tolerant of data sources, because data and processes are very different things and we aren't equipped to deal with data sources. I think that all questions here should solve a process problem, and that processes that require data sources (such as looking up a word in a dictionary) should make data sources out of scope of the question (either specify a data source and require interoperability, or request support for some common protocol). But we have no community consensus on that.

Answer (score 2):

I would say a off-line dictionary or Encyclopaedia (Eg Microsoft Encarta) can be on topic.
Where they exceed what would be expected of a normal document.

A language dictionary is more than documentation, such a 
 a dictionary program could provide features that would not be found in a mundane one.
For example a dictionary software may have a in built audio for pronunciation.
A PC Encyclopaedia could include video.

However if there is no requirement in the question, or in the answer "program" does not have such features, and is more or less a document, perhaps with indexing etc, would not software, it is a document.

For example this is the [Mathematica Manual](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LanguageOverview.html).
It is a fairly complex website, tons of styling and hyperlinks and pictures,
 but it is basically static.
Its a document.
The Help functionality built into Mathematica that will let you (for example) right click on a function and load its Manual Page, is a Feature of the Mathematica Software.
Even the inbuilt Help which is the same general content of

This is a borderline, for sure.
In general:
*If it has a **author** rather than a **developer**,
or if it is **written** rather than **programmed**,
then it is a document, not software.*