# Is looking for software as "data" within our scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have seen [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17498/open-source-java-project-with-good-test-coverage) today and read [this meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/813/94).

The question looks for projects that have good test coverage. The project shall then be used as input data for a program the OP has that does code analysis (as far as I understood).

So, while this question looks out for software (which would be on-topic) - it looks for software as data (which would be off-topic by the linked meta).

So, is it on topic or not?

Comment: If it is really **data**, it would be on-topic at http://OpenData.stackexchange.com

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Cool. I didn't know that SE site.

Comment: That's even part of [my canned responses](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/9a2899dd91618e8aa130) :)

Comment: Related: [Is asking for sample, illustrative code on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is **off-topic**. I does not try to solve a problem the user has anymore then looking for other data would. The fact that the data the OPs looks for happens to be software does not matter.

We serve recommendations for Software that fulfill a purpose on their own. While I think this is an interesting question, this is not the site for it.