# Where to ask for websites?

Tags: discussion

Now I saw [this](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites) question and knew I can't ask for websites, only webapps.

While a site for free PDF books can be a webapp, it's basically a website unless you want requirements/features that only webapps are capable of, but that's not my case here.

The question is: What Stack Exchange site do I ask for websites?

Answer (score 8):

There is a proposal for [Website Recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendation) in Area 51. So it doesn't exist now, but it might if it gets enough support.

Comment: Thanks for that. I can foresee regularly recommending it. @Niceman, I upvoted your question there and added a few of my own. Let's hope that the site takes off.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Website Recommendations proposal has been deleted.

Answer (score 6):

There is none. I personally use https://www.quora.com/ for this kind of requests.

Update 2016-05-01: There is a new proposal [Website recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92540/website-recommendations?referrer=AQx0849qiZ8aDHio0gR48w2) in Area 51, which has entered the commit phase a few days ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Website Recommendations proposal has been deleted.

Comment: @Tom Yes, that is a pity.

Comment: Do you know why it was deleted? Can it be brought back? There really is a need for one, considering how many of these questions I've seen closed on both Software Recs and Web Apps, and how many questions exist in both sites' Metas. A `Website Recommendations` would eliminate the need for the contentious Web app/website distinction for this site, and clean up both of the other sites from of all website-related questions, keeping them true to their actual advertised purposes (software and wep app use respectively).

Comment: @Hashim Explanation from the admin: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/on-proposals-soliciting-reviews-recommendations-comparisons-etc